# Uniform Convergence of $f_n^k$ and polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Suppose $f_n$ are continuous functions converging uniformly to $f$ on the compact interval $[a,b]$.
>
> a) Show that for any natural power $k$, the sequence $f_n^k$ converges uniformly to $f^k$ on [a,b].
>
> b) If $p$ is a polynomial, show that $p \circ f_n$ converges uniformly to $p \circ f$ on $[a,b]$.

For part a) We know that, since the sequence is uniformly convergent,

$$\mathrm{sup}||f_n - f ||=M_n \rightarrow 0$$

Now can I say,

$$\mathrm{sup}||f_n^k - f^k || = M_n^k\rightarrow 0$$

and hence it is uniformly convergent. I am a bit sceptical about this.

For b) I think all polynomials are continuous and bounded on an interval and hence uniformly convergent. Hence $p \circ f_n$ is uniformly convergent to $p \circ f$. But I don't know how to exactly prove it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you justify the assertion that $\sup\lVert f_n^k-f^k\rVert=M_n^k$?

Comment: I am not sure how to show that apart from doing the expansion, in that case maybe I can say it will always be less than $kM_n^k$?

Comment: Hint: If $k$ is a positive integer, $x^k - y^k = (x - y)(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2} y + \ldots + y^{k-1})$

Comment: So after using that expansion, I will get $\mathrm{sup} ||f_n^k - f^k|| \leq k M^k_n $ which tends to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty $ and that's why it's uniformly convergent? @RobertIsrael

Comment: @MakVish Yes, see also my answer below and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104584/the-sequence-f-nk-converges-uniformly-to-fk-on-a-b?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a) see also [The sequence $f_n^k$ converges uniformly to $f^k$ on $[a,b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104584/the-sequence-f-nk-converges-uniformly-to-fk-on-a-b?rq=1)

For b), note that a polynomial is a linear combination of powers. Use the triangle inequality and a) ,

Bonus question: prove the following more general result. Let $g:A\to \mathbb{R}$ be a [Lipschitz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) and $f_n,f:[a,b]\to A$. If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $[a,b]$ then $g\circ f_n$ converges uniformly to $g\circ f$ in $[a,b]$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Note the set $A$ should be conveniently chosen.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Then you don't need Lipschitz, just uniformly continuous.

Comment: Yes, but I hope that Lipschitz property is easier to be proved by OP. Your hint seems to  go in the same direction.